# How to skip divide by 0 error when calculating Score in python?

Tags: python, csv

I am running the function below on a very long CSV file. The function calculates the Z-score of the column MFE for every 50 lines. Some of these 50 lines contain just zeros, and therefore when calculating the Zscore the program stops because it can't divide by zero. How can I solve this problem, and instead of stopping the program running print a 0 for the z-score of these lines?

```
def doZscore(csv_file, n_random):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    row_start = 0
    row_end = n_random + 1
    step = n_random + 1
    zscore = []
    while row_end <= len(df):
         selected_rows = df['MFE'].iloc[row_start:row_end]
         arr = []
         for x in selected_rows:
              arr.append(float(x))
         scores = stats.zscore(arr)
         for i in scores:
              zscore.append(round(i, 3))
         arr.clear()
         row_start += step
         row_end += step
    df['Zscore'] = zscore
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as f:
         df.to_csv(f, index=False)
         f.close()
    return
```

The error I am getting is: 
/s/software/anaconda/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:2253: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide return (a - mns) / sstd

Comment: Just  note, when using a `with` statement, you do not need to close the file as the `with` statement will do that for you.

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: You ahould attach the exact error trace

Comment: @Tomerikoo the error is /s/software/anaconda/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:2253: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  return (a - mns) / sstd

Comment: Not here... edit the question

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of the two following options:

```
if sum(arr) == 0:
    scores = [0]
else:
    scores = stats.zscore(arr)
```

The re factored way is:

```
scores = [0] if sum(arr) == 0 else scores = stats.zscore(arr)
```

Both would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As long as that is what you want to do, you'd just check before `scores = stats.zscore(arr)` if your array is all 0s, make `scores = arr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `scores = stats.zscore(arr)` is where the division occurs? You could add a check to see if `arr`only contains zeroes, for example by using

```
if arr.count(0) == len(arr):
    scores = arr
else:
    scores = stats.zscore(arr)
```